# RegEx for number range from 0-100 with two decimals / comma and dot separated

Tags: regex

I am looking for a way to build the following RegEx:

- Should range from 0-100
- Should allow decimal numbers with two digits, e.g. 1.01 or 99.99, but not 100.01
- It should allow "." and "," as decimal separator as I need to use it for a multilingual system and both number format as supposed to be allowed

I found this RegEx here, which doesn't serve the 3rd need:

```
^(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?)$
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Just replace ***all*** `\.`s with `[.,]`

Comment: Thank you for your quick help Wiktor! Unfortunately the original RegEx seemed to have a problem as well. With ^(?:100(?:[.,]00?)?|\d?\d(?:[.,]\d\d?)?)$ and ^(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?)$ the system only lets me enter the number 100, everything else is not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: This issue is not related to the current question. Check your code.